# Cumulus CI: Error: 'xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c_sf_ids'

Tags: cumulusci

While trying to load data using Cumulus CI, I am getting below error:

```
Error: 'xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c_sf_ids'
```

I checked the cci.log file, and this is the stacktrace:

```
Error: 'xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c_sf_ids'
Run this command for more information about debugging errors: cci error --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/cli/cci.py", line 91, in main
    cli(args[1:], standalone_mode=False, obj=runtime)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/cli/task.py", line 181, in run_task
    task()
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/core/tasks.py", line 158, in __call__
    self.result = self._run_task()
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/tasks/bulkdata/load.py", line 149, in _run_task
    result = self._execute_step(after_step)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/tasks/bulkdata/load.py", line 181, in _execute_step
    step, query = self.configure_step(mapping)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/tasks/bulkdata/load.py", line 229, in configure_step
    query = self._query_db(mapping)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/tasks/bulkdata/load.py", line 342, in _query_db
    query = transformer.add_columns(query)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/tasks/bulkdata/query_transformers.py", line 24, in add_columns
    if self.columns_to_add:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/functools.py", line 993, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/sonal/.local/pipx/venvs/cumulusci/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cumulusci/tasks/bulkdata/query_transformers.py", line 55, in columns_to_add
    self.metadata.tables[f"{lookup.table}_sf_ids"]
KeyError: 'xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c_sf_ids'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I also checked query_transformers.py file, but I don't know Python. :) David, can you take a look?

This is an extract of yaml file. Please note that xxxxxx__Assignment__c is master object, and xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c is it's child:

```
Insert xxxxxx__Assignment__c:
    sf_object: xxxxxx__Assignment__c
    table: xxxxxx__Assignment__c
    fields:
        Id: sf_id
        xxxxxx__AssignmentName__c: xxxxxx__AssignmentName__c
    lookups:
        xxxxxx__CourseOffering__c:
            table: hed__Course_Offering__c


Insert xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c:
    sf_object: xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c
    table: xxxxxx__StudentAssignment__c
    fields:
        Id: sf_id
    lookups:
        xxxxxx__Assignment__c:
            table: xxxxxx__Assignment__c
            after: Insert xxxxxx__Assignment__c
```

Comment: Need to see more of the mapping file. Most likely the steps are in the wrong order or an `after` clause is missing. (The SQL script isn't needed).

Comment: I have updated post to include the yml file. @DavidReed

Comment: The script works fine till the creation of xxxxxx__Assignment__c records.

Comment: Is it possible that it's taking time for the assignment records to get created? There are triggers in place, and that maybe assignment records are not yet created, and we are trying to create student assignment records.